# How to access the resource files under a self-defined resource directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The Android Project Resource directories are located at,

```
app/src/main/res/drawable
app/src/main/res/layout
app/src/main/res/values
```

...

Suppose I would like to add a source file as,

```
app/src/main/res/myRes/res001.xml
```

Is it possible to read the resource info from my code? or my resource files are strictly restricted to the supported resource directories?

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I would like to add a source file as `app/src/main/res/myRes/res001.xml`

You should get a compile error, as you cannot invent new resource types. Either put that file in `res/xml/` (which can handle any sort of XML), `res/raw/` (which can handle any sort of file), or `assets/`.

Comment: When I add in Android Studio, there is no compilation error.

Comment: @SkyOasis: I'll try to reproduce that, and if so, I'll file an issue to get that fixed. Regardless, you cannot invent new resource types, except by creating your own custom build of Android and rolling that into a custom ROM. Use one of the alternatives that I outlined.

Comment: @SkyOasis: I can reproduce your scenario. The resource does not wind up in the APK, so not only will Android not know about your invented resource type, but the resource itself will not be available for use. I filed [a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199842) to have the build tools point this out, rather than quietly ignoring the resource.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decide on a type.

Androids resource system have specific directories for specific resource types. You can't just 'add a resource', you have to decide on the type, for example:

- a layout file res/layout/main.xml
- a generic XML file (which will be compressed) res/xml/somedata.xml, or
- a raw type (which will also be compressed, unless you name it with an uncompressable extension, like for example MP3) res/raw/mydata.json

That being said you can make gradle do anything, like for example include several resource directories, like main/res and release/res

Answer (score 1):

Custom resources are not supported by Android. You must use any of the predefined structure folders of Android. If you still would like to add custom resources use `/res/xml` for xml resources and /res/assets for all other resources like fonts, text files etc.

[This link may help](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)